# Why is a shared partial view in a nested layout not working in a Rails functional test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in `app/views/foo/index.rhtml`:

```
  <% render :layout => 'bar_group', :locals => {:id => 'gold_bars'} do %>
    <%= render :partial => "bar_score_box", :locals => {:scores => scores} %>
    <%= render :partial => "common/translate_bar_link", :locals => {:bar => bar} %>
  <% end %>
```

`_bar_group.rhtml` and `_bar_score_box.rhtml` are both also in `app/views/foo/`, but `_translate_bar_link.rhtml` is in `app/views/common/`.

This view works just fine when running my Rails app in development mode and hitting it with a web browser. But when I run a functional test that hits the view, I get an error like this:

```
Exception: Missing template _translate_bar_link.erb in view path
app/views/foo/_bar_group.rhtml:2
```

`app/views/foo/_bar_group.rhtml` looks something like this:

```
<div id="<%= id %>" class="tile">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

So the error is being reported on the `yield` line.

Again, this works fine through the Rails server, but not when running a functional test. Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here?

**Update:** It turns out that I had a second render call for the same partial later in my view, which I forgot to change to `common/translate_bar_link` when I moved the partial from `app/views/foo` to `app/views/common`:

```
    <%= render :partial => "translate_bar_link", :locals => {:bar => bar} %>
```

Operator error. Sorry for wasting your time. Flagging this question for deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Try tinkering around with the path used in your render(:partial) statements.

Example (notice the slash in front of 'common/translate_bar_link'):

```
<% render :layout => 'bar_group', :locals => {:id => 'gold_bars'} do %>
  <%= render :partial => "bar_score_box", :locals => {:scores => scores} %>
  <%= render :partial => "/common/translate_bar_link", :locals => {:bar => bar} %>
<% end %>
```

Also, sometimes it helps to put the file extension, too, like this (notice the .rhtml):

```
<% render :layout => 'bar_group', :locals => {:id => 'gold_bars'} do %>
  <%= render :partial => "bar_score_box", :locals => {:scores => scores} %>
  <%= render :partial => "/common/translate_bar_link.rhtml", :locals => {:bar => bar} %>
<% end %>
```

I am not sure what version of Rails you are using, but maybe you can rename `common/translate_bar_link.rhtml` to `common/translate_bar_link.html.erb`

Comment: It turns out this was operator error, as I've edited my question to note. I'll also request its deletion, as it is not useful at all to the community. :-/